# MySQLI Update set +1 the correct form and symbols

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, insert

EDIT;
there is no error and all other things work but updating I just get no +1 :( nothing gets updated- Maybe because I am using wrong quotes?

I am looking on internet some people uses the following kind of query

```
UPDATE `attempts` SET `fails` = fails+1 WHERE id='3'"
```

I am confused because others uses

```
UPDATE `attempts` SET `fails` = `fails` +1 WHERE id='3'"
```

and

```
UPDATE `attempts` SET `fails` = +1 WHERE id='3'"
```

Which form is the correct one while inserting to MySQL and I mean also the symbols used. Some uses symbols some others don´t and that makes me confused. This questions is about symbols and correct form when inserting data

Just need to know what is the correct form when to use `` when ' ' and when " " in this query only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Please add it as answer to mark it as correct –  Cardinale 4 mins ago"*

**After multiple comments:**

Your `fails` column's length is set too low; you need to increase it.

`fails INT 1` do `fails INT 10`

Plus, you can use any of your present queries but remove the quotes in

```
WHERE id='3'
```

it's an integer

```
WHERE id=3
```

---

**Edit:** Added a PDO example with prepared statements; adjust to suit.

```
<?php 
$servername = "xxx"; // Modify
$username   = "xxx"; // these
$password   = "xxx"; // for
$dbname     = "xxx"; // your own

try {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = 'UPDATE `your_table` SET col = col + 1 WHERE id = :id';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $userid));

     }
catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

Comment: Fred. If I update where IP then I add the quotes ' o right? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Cardinale Yes, i.e. `UPDATE attempts SET fails = +1 WHERE id=3 AND IP='123.456.789'` for example. and you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

- ` is used to denote an object name, such as a table or column
- ' is used to denote a string literal

So, the correct syntax, assuming that `id` is numeric, should be:

```
UPDATE `attempts` SET `fails` = `fails` + 1 WHERE id = 3
```

Using `SET fails = +1` won't increment `fails`, it will simply set it to a positive 1.

Comment: @Cardinale If you think any answer was useful/helpful you can upV it!